# How to launch command with piped output in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to write a launch.json entry. The structure looks like below :

```
        {
        "name": "Test LLC",
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "path_to_bin/llc",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "args": ["-march=arch1","-mcpu=abc","${file}","|","prog2","-arg2","val2"]
    }
```

I am trying to pipe the output of the first program to second executable. This works fine in normal terminal, however it throws an error saying "-arg2" is not a valid option for prog1 (llc). I think VSCode somehow validating all the options in a position independent way, is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: the pipe symbol will be escaped/quoted on the command line, start the pipe in a script/bat file and attach the debugger to the `llc` process